# dynamic interval after emitting item in rxjava

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I am trying to add dynamic internal for the list items that have been emitted using `RxJava`.

Currently in my flow after every 10 seconds I am emitting the items but what I am trying to achieve is there will be a delay of 60 seconds after emitting first item then rest of the items will continue following 10 seconds of delay.

1. item #1 emit
2. 60 seconds delay
3. item #1 emit
4. 10 seconds delay
5. item #2 emit
6. 10 seconds delay and so on

My current code is as follows

```
.flatMap(dataList -> Observable.fromIterable(dataList)
            .zipWith(Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS), (item, interval) -> item)
            .doOnNext(data -> {
                
            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of a `just()` and an `interval()` with initial delay of 60

```java
.zipWith(
        Observable.just(-1L)
        .concatWith(Observable.interval(60, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)), 
        (item, interval) -> item
)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit about the approach

Comment: You can create the required timing via just and the initially delayed interval.